# Game Center Outcome Posting

Tags: ios, game-center

I’m doing a turn based game... the only information transferred is the score of the player and whether a turn has been sent.

When the next player receives the turn.  The data gets stored into “scoreToBeat”  and turnSent=1.  The player then takes their turn.  Afterward the game ended gets called because turnSent=1.  I used the turn based tutorial by Ray Wenderlich at http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1.

In his case the game ends and is a tie. Like this...   I can’t seem to get it to show the person that lost.

```
   for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *part in currentMatch.participants) {           
          part.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;
           }
```

I can’t seem to get it to show the person that lost it always shows a win.  This is my latest attempt of many...  Exactly 2 players in the match btw...  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
    for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *part in currentMatch.participants) {           
           if(part==currentMatch.currentParticipant)
           {
               if(points>scoreToBeat)
               {
                   part.matchOutcome=GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;   
               }
               else {
                   part.matchOutcome=GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;
               }
           }
           else {
               if(points>scoreToBeat)
               {
                   part.matchOutcome=GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;   
               }
               else {
                   part.matchOutcome=GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
               }

           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an excerpt from my latest project, good for a 2 player game. It's called during the sendTurn process, when the game is decided to be ending. This is more correct than the previous answer (first code block), in my opinion, because you must set the matchOutcome for all participants before ending the game.

If you had more than 2 players, then you'd have to loop through all participants and set the matchOutcome accordingly.

```
   GKTurnBasedParticipant *curr = currentMatch.currentParticipant;
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [currentMatch.participants indexOfObject:currentMatch.currentParticipant];
    NSUInteger nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % [currentMatch.participants count];
    GKTurnBasedParticipant *next = [currentMatch.participants objectAtIndex:nextIndex];

    if (currScore < otherScore)
    {
        // Curr player lost
        curr.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;
        next.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
    }
    else if (currScore == otherScore)
    {
        // Tied
        curr.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;
        next.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Won
        curr.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
        next.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;
    }
```

Note that you will see "Won" on both devices by design.

One will say "Me" with "Won" underneath, and the other will say "(Winners Name)" with "Won" underneath.

Answer (score 2):

points is the local points scored on the device right? if so, I would do the following:

```
  if([part.playerID isEqualToString [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID]]) {

 if(points>scoreToBeat) {

part.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutComeWon;

} else {

part.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutComeLost;

} 

} else { 
    if(points>scoreToBeat) {
               part.matchOutcome=GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;   
           } else {
               part.matchOutcome=GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
           }

       }
}
```

Also, remember to use a NSLog to see if score to beat is actually transferred. One mistake you can do to keep on using currentTurnBasedMatch.matchData, you should set the currentTurnBasedMatch to GKTurnBasedMatch that is returned in delegate methods.

EDIT: A code snipped I use looks like this

```
if([participant.playerID isEqualToString:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID]){
        NSLog(@"we are the last player in the game -end the game");
        for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *part in match.participants) {

            part.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;
        }
       [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:match.matchData completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
           if ([AppDelegate mainMenuController].multiGameMenu.turnBasedMenu !=nil) {

               [[AppDelegate mainMenuController].multiGameMenu.turnBasedMenu reloadTableView];
           }

       } ];
}
```

Comment: I have put NSLog’s everywhere... it goes through the logic correct and for example says the player should lose.  I don’t do anything with the match data after this part... just use  [currentMatch endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:data 
                                completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                    }
                                }];  Maybe that’s the problem.

Comment: <GKTurnBasedParticipant 93952a0 - id:G:1126405031 status:Done outcome:Won lastTurn:2012-05-09 21:04:37 +0000>

Comment: So just to make sure, you call the given method before ending the match right? Because every player should have a match outcome before you end a match. You can maybe try to set the matchOutcome to GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost for every player and to see if it works then (if it doesn't its really weird).. As for my app, I set the outcome to GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied in any case since I use a custom table view for displaying the games, so the game results are just calculated/decided locally using the matchData.

Comment: I changed everything to lost.. and both come up as lost.  So there is some error apparently.  Still trying to tinker with it.