# Xcode: How do I end a 2 player turn based multiplayer match with a winner and loser using GameCenter?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gamekit

I've had a bit of trouble finding any information on this and all the code samples I come across are based on the match ending in a tie for all players. In my 2 player turn based game I want to be able to end the match with a winner and loser. With the below code I've written the match always ends with the same result for both players, if its a win then both player 1 and 2 win, if its a loss both player 1 and 2 loose... any help? Thank you.

```
    if (gameOver == true) {
    if (GameWinner == 0) {
        GKTurnBasedParticipant *player0 = [currentMatch.participants objectAtIndex:0];
        player0.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
        GKTurnBasedParticipant *player1 = [currentMatch.participants objectAtIndex:1];
        player1.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;

        [currentMatch endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }];  
        testlabel.text = @"Player 1 Wins!";
    } else if (GameWinner == 1) {
        GKTurnBasedParticipant *player0 = [currentMatch.participants objectAtIndex:0];
        player0.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;
        GKTurnBasedParticipant *player1 = [currentMatch.participants objectAtIndex:1];
        player1.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;

        [currentMatch endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }];
        testlabel.text = @"Player 2 Wins!";
    } else if (GameWinner == 2) {
        for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *part in currentMatch.participants) {
            part.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;
        }
        [currentMatch endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }];
        testlabel.text = @"Tie Game!";
    } else {
        testlabel.text = @"Your turn is over.";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521778/game-center-outcome-posting) SO Question, try:

```
GKTurnBasedParticipant *curr = currentMatch.currentParticipant;
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [currentMatch.participants indexOfObject:currentMatch.currentParticipant];
    NSUInteger nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % [currentMatch.participants count];
    GKTurnBasedParticipant *next = [currentMatch.participants objectAtIndex:nextIndex];

    if (currScore < otherScore)
    {
        // Curr player lost
        curr.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;
        next.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
    }
    else if (currScore == otherScore)
    {
        // Tied
        curr.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;
        next.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeTied;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Won
        curr.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
        next.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel kind of silly now, the code via the link didn't help but the explanation of how it appears in each players view controller did, my code above was working as planned I just didn't realise the view controller always says "won" regardless of wether you were the victor or loser. Thanks for the point in the right direction.